# show and hide menu in adapter android studio

Tags: android, menu, show-hide

I am trying to hide and show toolbar and menu on long press of the button. When the button is pressed, the menu inflates and the toolbar disappears very seamlessly. But when I try to hide the menu and show the toolbar, for a moment you can see both the menu and the toolbar on the top of the screen and then the toolbar appears and menu hides. It looks very ugly and disturbs the whole view of the screen.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
 public MyAdapter(Activity activity,Toolbar toolbar) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
}

 public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
            position) {
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
             MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                   toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mode_menu, menu);
                   return true;
             }
              public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                 long_click_toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  mode.getMenu().close(); // for hiding the menu
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **setOnLongClickListener()** in the ViewHolder class not in the onBindViewHolder().
For details read this [Blog](https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problems remains as before when I put that in ViewHolder class